# LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates description

Tags: android, location

Can someone please explain to me what the line below does:

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
```

This is my code for mLocationRequest:

```
mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
```

Is  LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates just a listener that will update the location according to the interval that is set? If that is the case does it just need to be set once during the Activity lifecycle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi.html#requestLocationUpdates(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest,%20com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener)) is really helpful! The third argument is your listener, the second is the request specifying the criteria you want from the location updates, the location updates will call `onLocationUpdate` in your `LocationListener`.